# gcsfuse fstab configuration with google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

I am running freepbx Centos on a GCE VM. Syncing stops when FreePBX/Asterisk tries to write and create a folder in the mounted folder and FreePBX is unable to write / create folder in the folder. Everything works again when the system is rebooted because gcsfuse is no longer mounted.

**gcsfuse works when:**

-create a folder /var/spool/asterisk/cloud.
-mount it using gcsfuse --implicit-dirs siphqrecordings /var/spool/asterisk/cloud.
-create a sample text file nano test.txt.
-it syncs up to my bucket just fine

**It completely stops working when:**

-FreePBX tries to place a file and folder in the directory (a recorded call), the folder and file never gets written. I have unmount/reboot the server and then freepbx is able to use the folder and write files and directories to it. Even if I try to create a manual file using nano it never sync up.

FreePBX is unable to write to folder mounted with gcsfuse and the sync stops even for manually created files.

I think I need to somehow mount it in FSTAB but dont know-how… the user is root on the folder but asterisk is the user posting to the folder, so it's probably some kind of permissions?

drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Nov 21 15:45 cloud

drwxrwxr-x. 2 asterisk asterisk 6 May 2 2018 fax

drwxrwxr-x. 2 asterisk asterisk 6 Nov 21 15:44 incron

Answer (score 2):

OK I got it to work:

nano /etc/fstab

mybucket /var/spool/asterisk/cloud gcsfuse rw,allow_other,file_mode=777,dir_mode=777